# Plotting value in gnuPlot from text file

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot a graph in gnuplot. I have the file :

```
2.62    Mean
2.46    Median
3.8     80%
6.93    Maximum
```

Now, I want to plot y value as col1 and xvalue as col2.

I am writing :

```
plot 'C:\Users\abc\Desktop\cc.dat' with linespoints
```

But, only y value comes. can anyone please help me out

Comment: The trouble that you are running into is a little basic. You should be able to figure it out by looking at tutorials on the net. I pulled these ones up from Google: http://people.duke.edu/~hpgavin/gnuplot.html and http://www.gnuplot.info/docs/tutorial.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The second column is a string. If you want to put that on the x-axis, you must use `xticlabel(2)` to put these values as manual tic labels:

```
plot 'cc.dat' using 0:1:xtic(2) with linespoints
```

The zeroth column, i.e. the row number, is used as x-values, the first column as y-values and the second column as manual xtics.